# Replacing plain text in HTML file, using js function

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying this graph visualization library from [here](https://g6.antv.vision/en)

They supplied this experimental code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Tutorial Demo</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    /* The container of the graph */
    <div id="mountNode"></div>

    /* Import G6 by CDN */
    <script src="https://gw.alipayobjects.com/os/antv/pkg/_antv.g6-3.7.0/dist/g6.min.js"></script>

    <script>
      // Define the source data
      const data = {
        // The array of nodes
        nodes: [
          {
            id: 'node1',
            x: 100,
            y: 200,
          },
          {
            id: 'node2',
            x: 300,
            y: 200,
          },
        ],
        // The array of edges
        edges: [
          // An edge links from node1 to node2
          {
            source: 'node1',
            target: 'node2',
          },
        ],
      };

      // Instantiate a Graph
      const graph = new G6.Graph({
        container: 'mountNode', // The id of the container
        // The width and height of the graph
        width: 800,
        height: 500,
      });
      // Load the data
      graph.data(data);
      // Render the graph
      graph.render();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I want to switch this code part:

```
 nodes: [
              {
                id: 'node1',
                x: 100,
                y: 200,
              },
              {
                id: 'node2',
                x: 300,
                y: 200,
              },
            ],
```

With a function that I created on a js file, lets call it test.js which includes:

```
function getArr()
{
    arr = [
        { id: 'node1', x: 100, y: 200 },
        { id: 'node2', x: 200, y: 200 },
      ]
    return arr;
}
```

So I changed to the following:

```
 <script src="test.js">
      // Define the source data
      const data = {
        // The array of nodes
        nodes: getArr(),
        // The array of edges
        edges: [
          // An edge links from node1 to node2
          {
            source: 'node1',
            target: 'node2',
          },
        ],
      };
```

However, it doesn't work. Presumably, I was supposed to get the same results, but I am probably missing something over here.

Would love to know how to solve it.

Comment: A script tag with an `src` ignores text code within the tag

Comment: @charlietfl

So how can I fix this?

Comment: Use separate script tags or combine both in the file

Comment: @charlietfl Could you please demonstrate?

Comment: Never mind, just saw the last part. @willyJS It's quite simple: Either load a JS file with `<script src="file.js"></script>` or directly add js code with `<script>code</script>`. You can't combine both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following example is working for me.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Tutorial Demo</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://gw.alipayobjects.com/os/antv/pkg/_antv.g6-3.7.0/dist/g6.min.js"></script>
    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="save.js" ></script>
  </head>
  <body>    
    <div id="mountNode"></div>
    <script>
      const data = {
        nodes: getArr(),
        edges: [          
          {
            source: 'node1',
            target: 'node2',
          },
        ],
      };
      const graph = new G6.Graph({
        container: 'mountNode',
        width: 800,
        height: 500,
      });
      graph.data(data);
      graph.render();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

my `save.js` is

```
function getArr(){
    arr = [
        { id: 'node1', x: 100, y: 200 },
        { id: 'node2', x: 200, y: 200 }
    ];
    return arr;
}
```